# Getting a list of the ops for an IRC channel

Tags: irc

How do I get a list of ops for an irc channel, and the type of op that they are?

I could not find this help on http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/opguide.html

Comment: It varies by network. What network are you asking about?

Comment: irc.mozilla.org

Answer (score 8):

The `names` command will list all users in a channel and give their ranks beside them. Ops on a typical server are denoted with an `@` beside their name, halfops with `%`, and voiced users with `+`, and owners are `~` (on some networks owners do not get a `~`, they are just ops (`@`) with an extra mode set on them, `+q`, that gives them control of the channel).

Edit: There is a command `/msg chanserv access #channel list` that will show ops and privileged users on a channel if the listings are not private.

There is most likely a way, depending on your client, to write a little script to sort out the ops of a channel, but I am in no shape or form a competent programmer.

As David said, these commands are server specific, but the identifiers for the channel position are as well. The commands and rank signs I listed are typical on most networks I frequent.

If you need any further detail just leave a comment.